# JSON - There are no child objects

Tags: javascript, json, weather-api

I am trying to retrieve some specific data, using jQuery to retrieve a JSON Feed.

This is what I am currently doing:

```
var url  = 'https://api.wunderground.com/api/myapicode/conditions/forecast/q/Tokyo.json?callback=?';

$.getJSON(url, function(d){
    var data = d['current_observation'];
    console.dir(data['display_location']);
});
```

This successfully returns to the console:

```
city ==> "Tokyo"
country ==> "JP"
country_iso3166 ==> "JP"
elevation  ==> "8.00000000"
full ==> "Tokyo, Japan"
latitude ==> "35.54999924"
etc...
```

However, let's say I want to get just the "full" name.  If I try:

```
  console.dir(data['display_location']['full']);
```

I end up getting the result: `There are no child objects`

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`console.dir` displays the properties (child objects) of the object you pass it.
It doesn't make sense to call it with a string.

You should call `console.log` instead.

Answer (score 2):

in order to use `console.dir(arg)` arg should be an object. You are accessing a `full` key of an object in `console.dir(data['display_location']['full']);` which is a plain string. 
use `console.log(data['display_location']['full'])` instead

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `console.log()` to get a value instead of an object's properties.

Answer (score 1):

[`console.dir`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console.dir) will show object trees - the properties of the *object* you pass in. Yet, the property you log is just a string and has *no child objects*. Use [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console.log) instead.